# How to read ( spos and pos ) touch position on a kivy program

Tags: python, kivy, shapes

I am writing a code in which I am drawing ellipses on touch command in an empty canvas. How do I read the position of touch (spos, pos) individually  on the code and use them elsewhere on the code.

Comment: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/inputs.html

Comment: We need more information about your question. Please, add your sample code to fix errors. You should know that, Stack Overflow is not a platform for tutorial, but you can utilize it for fixing your codes' errors.